# Using unicodedata.normalize in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization

Once again, I am very confused with a unicode question. I can't figure out how to successfully use [unicodedata.normalize](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) to convert non-ASCII characters as expected. For instance, I want to convert the string

```
u"Cœur"
```

To

```
u"Coeur"
```

I am pretty sure that unicodedata.normalize is the way to do this, but I can't get it to work. It just leaves the string unchanged.

```
>>> s = u"Cœur"
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s) == s
True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem seems not to have to do with Python, but that the character you are trying to decompose (u'\u0153' - 'œ') is not a composition itself.

Check as your code works with a string containing normal composite characters like "ç" and "ã":

```
>>> a1 = a
>>> a = u"maçã"
>>> for norm in ('NFC', 'NFKC', 'NFD','NFKD'):
...    b = unicodedata.normalize(norm, a)
...    print b, len(b)
... 
maçã 4
maçã 4
maçã 6
maçã 6
```

And then, if you check the unicode reference for both characters (yours and  c + cedila) you will see that the later has a "decomposition" specification the former lacks:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/153/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e7/index.htm

It like "œ" is not formally equivalent to "oe" - (at least not for the people who defined this unicode part) - so, the way to go to normalize text containing this is to make a manual replacement of the char for the sequence with unicode.replace - as hacky as it sounds.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure unicodedata.normalize was what I wanted. But I did figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 21):

You could try [`Unidecode`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unidecode import unidecode # $ pip install unidecode

print(unidecode(u"Cœur"))
# -> Coeur
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Short and simple and gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

As jsbueno says, some letters just don't have a compatibility decomposition.

You can use the [Unicode CLDR Latin-ASCII transform](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/transforms/Latin-ASCII.xml) to generate a mapping of manual replacements.